# Makefile - Automatically run all programs

Tags: makefile

I have this in my Makefile:

```
%.x: %.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

So this generates executable files ending with .x
Now I would like to run all these executables one by one, something like:

```
run:
   <execute *.x>
```

, but I want to avoid typing all the names

```
run:
    ./a.x
    ./b.x
```

(How) can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to run all the `.x` executables that exist? Or all that exist or can be built (building as necessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
run:
        for x in *.x; do ./$$x; done
```

Comment: I get this error when I do 'make run' with your answer:
 make run
for x in *.x; do ./; done;
/bin/sh: ./: is a directory
/bin/sh: ./: is a directory
make: *** [run] Error 126

Comment: As you can see, it tries to "do ./", which means $x returned an empty string. Am I right?

Comment: Ok got it. The $x should be $$x

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry about that. Fixed.